# Struggling with how to fix my R code in a population model

Tags: r

new here, but I am currently working through a simple population modelling project and am struggling with how to rectify the error message I receive when I run the following;

```
N<-array(0,dim=c(16,50))

N[1,1] <- 37

for(x in 2:50){  
  for(y in 1:16){
    N[x,1]<-N[x, 1]+N[psiage,x]*0.765[psiage]

  }
  for(x in 2:16){
    N[y,x] <- N[psiage,i]*survivalrate[psiage]
  }
}
```

(here psiage just refers to the numbers 1-16 and survival rate corresponds to 16 values)

I get the error message

```
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What is `psiage`? What is `survivalrate`?

Comment: hi! I think I mentioned above, but psiage refers to the age of the organisms (and consist of the numbers 1-16), while survival rate refers to 16 values, each corresponding to a survival rate at each age.

Comment: this is not enough to go on to help you. We need data that exemplifies these in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oh, my bad! survival rate is this ```[1] 0.4029451 0.7353952 0.8297872 0.8910891 0.9382716 0.8417266 0.7894737 0.7553191 0.6046512
[10] 0.5714286 0.4324324 0.4047619 0.5555556 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.0000000
> ```

Comment: Why do you reverse the x.y indices for the second assignment? And why change the value of `x` inside the for loop. IN one place it's a n time and another its an age. ???) I'm unable to make sense of that swap.And what are you trying to do with `0.765[psiage]`? You cannot index a numeric value.